# How to customize sub-URLs in a wordpress website (.htaccess)

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, htaccess

I have a regular business website that I built on Wordpress - www.example.com

I have a blog page in my website under - www.example.com/blog

When viewing a blog post it looks like this: www.exmaple.com/[category]/[posts-name]

How can I add "/blog" to this URL before the category? 
like this: www.exmaple.com/blog/[category]/[posts-name]

This is my current .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do that viw .htaccess because .htacces rules can not control how the permalinks are generated by WordPress. Instead, go to WordPress settings->permalink. Select custom structure and enter:

```
blog/%category%/%postname%
```

Comment: I already have `/%category%/%postname%/` there. I think that will change my homepage URL to `www.example.com/blog`, which I don't want to happen.

Comment: Actually worked! Now I don't think I understand enough how all the permalinks work on WP :/

Do you have a tutorial that exmplane exactly how the permalinks work on WP ?

Comment: The configuration in settings->permalink is for posts, tags and categories. The URL for site is configured in settings->general. About a tutorial, I don't remember any one but you can start with [Using permalinks entry in the codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks). Further modificacions may need the use of [the_permalink filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink) and [Rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API).

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> Permalink and type in Custom structure.

```
/blog/%postname%
```